# Joining tables with the same name and schema from multiple databases in MySQL

Tags: mysql

So we have 23 databases with the same schema and table names. I need to fetch all the data from a table called `inventory` which is present in all the dbs.

The possible solution I can think of is doing a UNION ALL, but that means I'll have to do a union 22 times.
Is there a shorter, easier faster way this can be done?

Comment: Nope, there is not. You can use sql sratement (or other scripting) to generate the unions for you, you can wrap the select into a view, but neither affects the speed of the query and franky copy pasting the same table name with different database name 21 times is not going to be any slower than trying to write a script to generate the sql statement.

Comment: Flaw in schema design:  "23 databases with the same schema and table names".

Comment: Yes @RickJames, i know that. Unfortunately it's not under my control. It would be great if you could suggest some solution instead of pointing out the obvious

Comment: @newby100 - Apologies to you, but it is not obvious to some programmers on this site.

Comment: What will you then do with the data?  INSERT it into a single table?  Filter some info out of it?  Display the data?  Dump to another server?  (There may be different solutions for different situations.)